# xv6 Start new process and exec user program

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel, xv6

I'm trying to `fork()` a new process and `exec()` the the user program in newly created process.

This code works in user space. I'm not sure how to do the similar thing in kernel space. As per my debugging, seems like `fork()` never returns 0 in kernel space.

Additional question: How can I execute the user program from kernel space. Is it possible to do that with `exec()`?

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
    // child
        char *argv[2];
        argv[0] = "echo";
        argv[1] = "CHILD";
        exec("/bin/echo", argv);
        exit();
        
        
    }
    if(pid > 0) {
        wait();

        printf("parent");
    }   
    else {
        printf("ERROR");

    }   
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You want to invoke a usermode program from a kernel context? Have you had a look at call_usrmodehelper?